# Tkinter or Pygame which should I use

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm about to start programming a game for my computing A level. The game will be a version of scrabble but won't have a board. It will be how many words can you make in an amount of time. The game will also have menus, buttons and logins for different users to access the game. I'm wanting to know if it would be better to use Tkinter or Pygame for this or if I can use aspects of both: eg Tkinter for menus and Pygame for the main loop. Any help would be much appreciated I'm quite new to both these ideas so please explain any specialist terminology. Thanks a lot

Comment: you should use tkinter

Comment: for the game loop as well?

Comment: It depends on your method of programming.  Most would prefer Pygame over TKinter (I do), but there are other options.  PyOpenGL, for example, is very high performance, but is also very difficult to use.  Pyglet is another possibility.  My recommendation is to learn the basics for all of them via their main documentation and/or books, and then decide which works best for you.

Answer (score 4):

SO, expanding the issue:
I love Pygame, in that it offers a simple API for one to draw things on a screen-canvas, and a nice O.O. hierarchy and tooling for sprites and game objects on screen.

It happens it does not offer any support for menus, or buttons, or even text-entry - you have to either use a third party module for that, or code all from scratch yourself. You have to implement things like reading the keyboard code, drawing the corresponding glyph on the correct location on the canvas - and the keyboard reading is raw, and won't give you things like character composition provided by the O.S. - which might be important in a word related application.

In short: you need a fully featured app, and should be using tkinter for that. As for the mainloop: you have to use Tkinter's loop and implement
`after` event calls to get the control to parts of your code that have to initiate actions.

Pygame gives you full control of the mainloop  - and I like that for  learning purposes - but most gaming or GUI toolkits have their all mainloop, and you have to register your callbacks.

It is even possible to have an application that have the "control screens" - menus, buttons, logins, and so on, written in Tkinter and the main game screen, where the action takes place, made in Pygame. That won't solve Pygame's hard-to-install problems, and may look awkward for the players themselves.

For multimedia-stuff I am moving my projects to Pyglet, since it is a well behaved Python module,and have some capabilities pygame lacks. But Tkinter can do pretty nice things in its `Canvas` widget, and sure enough could hld your game.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used any of them ? If the answer to that is yes, then you should pick the more familiar one. The pick does not really matter if it is going to be a simple scrabble game with not a lot of animations. Personally, I think that Tkinter is easier.

Comment: I have used both but not in much detail. So was just wondering which would be easier with me making both menu based systems and a game

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is the best choice for games, tkinter is more friendly for make utilities softwares. Tkinter have limitations, you will be freeze in some steps and have double of time to figure out. You can also use Pyglet, is easiest than, but Pygame still the best choice, fast, lot of functionality, you can do all things you want.